# collectd-web by remote access

Tags: ssh, remote-access, collectd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEwbx.jpg)I want to use collectd-web to monitor my system on minimal centos 6. ( I use ssh to remote to my machine) I've installed and configured collectd and collectd-web. when I enter my ip:8888 in my browser it just shows Menu and doesn't show any graph! what should I do now?